# Laravel - Setting session variables when using Basic Auth

Tags: laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5.1, basic-authentication

I'm implementing an API so that clients can access our system. I'm currently using Auth Basic for authentication. Is there a way for me to set additional session variables when they authenticate this way?

There are session variables we usually set when they log in from the login page, and so there is functionality that depends on those values. So I'll need a way to set those same variables, but when using the Auth Basic middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own basic auth controllers and functions as described in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users)

Your authentication controller would look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```